# Looping every 5 counts with while?

Tags: python

I am trying to build a loop for the following logic:

start count at 2 and add +5 for every iteration (in this case, 85 times). Inside this loop, for every time you add a +5, do another loop inside it: add a +1 to the count and generate a random number.

(Let me know if this is unclear)

This is the code I have:

```
count = 2
new_count = 0 

while count < 86:
    print("this is iteration number:" + str(count))
    while new_count < 5:
        value = randint(5,10)
        print(value)
        new_count += 1
    count += 5
```

but this is the output I get:

```
this is iteration number:2
7
5
8
5
6
this is iteration number:7
this is iteration number:12
this is iteration number:17
this is iteration number:22
```

Why does it not continue the inner loop for the next iterations? Thank you!

Comment: you need to reset new_count, currently it is adding new count to 5, then it stays 5 for all the other loops, so never goes into the inner loop, try adding a statement `new_count = 0` just above the `while new_count < 5:`

Comment: it worked, thank you!!

Comment: I know, it just didn't let me accept an answer within the first 10 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your `new_count` variable is not reset to `0`. Set `new_count = 0` into the first `while` loop and that should fix your problem

Answer (score 0):

`new_count` isn't reset to zero. It is automatically bypassing the second for loop. You just need to set `new_count` to zero in the first for loop.